# What is the meaning of ARM LDAXR/STLXR instructions?

Tags: ida, disassembly, arm

Often while disassembling `ARM` files, I see some code snippet with the following pattern:

```
loc_BB30:
.text:C0 FE 5F 88 LDAXR           WZR, W0, [X22]
.text:00 04 00 51 SUB             W0, W0, #1
.text:C0 FE 01 88 STLXR           W1, W0, [X22]
.text:A1 FF FF 35 CBNZ            W1, loc_BB30
```

Which is translated to the following decompile code:

```
  do
  {
    v2 = __ldaxr((unsigned int *)v1);
    v1 = (unsigned int)(v1 - 1);
  }
  while ( __stlxr(v1, v3) );
```

What is the meaning of this code? What kind of c code actually produces this kind of snippet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This general pattern of exclusive-access instructions is usually seen when atomic variables are modified.

**C++ Example (C++11 or later)**

```
  #include <atomic>

  void release( std::atomic<int>& refcount ) {
      refcount--;
  }
```

You can see [here on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/PvTK8o) that GCC's ARM64 compilation of the above produces your assembly code.

**C Example (C11)**

```
#include <stdatomic.h>

void release( _Atomic int* refcount ) {
    (*refcount)--;
}
```

Godbolt version [here](https://godbolt.org/z/5ve8c5)

**C Example (prior to C11, using GCC built-ins)**

```
void release( int* refcount ) {
    __atomic_sub_fetch( refcount, 1, __ATOMIC_ACQ_REL );
}
```

Godbolt version [here](https://godbolt.org/z/1687vr)